# How to prove this inequality of dispersion?

Tags: probability, inequality

> Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ be a probabilistic space. Let $X,Y$ be two independent
> real random variables which admit $f$ and $g$ respectively as
> distribution function. Suppose that both $\mathbb{E}[\vert X\vert], \mathbb{E}[\vert Y\vert]< \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X]=0=\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Then $\mathbb{E}[\vert X-Y\vert]\ge \mathbb{E}[\vert X\vert]$.

Here is my attempt :

We first show a lemma : for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ : $\mathbb{E}[\vert x-Y\vert]\ge \vert x\vert$.

Indeed, let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the properties of expectation give : $\mathbb{E}[\vert x-Y\vert]\ge\vert \mathbb{E}[x-Y] \vert= \vert \mathbb{E}[x] -\mathbb{E}[Y]\vert= \vert \mathbb{E}[x] \vert= \vert x\vert$.

Now taking $x = \mathbb{E}[\vert X \vert]$, we can deduce that $\mathbb{E}[\vert \mathbb{E}[\vert X\vert] - Y \vert]\ge \vert \mathbb{E}[\vert X\vert]\vert$.

It remains to show that $\mathbb{E}[\vert X-Y\vert]\ge \mathbb{E}[\vert\mathbb{E}[\vert X\vert] - Y \vert]$ (notice that $\mathbb{E}[\vert X- Y\vert] < \infty$ by the triangle inequality).

But I am not sure, I know that I did not use yet the fact that $X,Y$ are independents and have distribution functions (I have the feeling that this last assumption is useless though). A hint would be much appreciated !

Also, are there generalizations of these kind of inequalities ? I mean with weakening the assumptions for instance...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I tried using the inverse triangle inequality $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$, but it didn’t work. The simplest solution in see is using the distributions $f,g$. Maybe there is a simpler solution, i can’t tell.

Comment: @Eric Thank you, how would you use the distributions $f$ and $g$ then ?

Comment: @Mittens Thank you, I think it is related ! I guess in your proof it is the same reasoning for $\vert X-Y\vert$ instead of $\vert X+Y \vert$ !? However, no use of the distributions functions in your proof. Hence I guess it must work for any random variables $X,Y$ (independents)...

Comment: @Maman: I made changes to the posting I linked earlier. Independence  is in a way an application of Fubini's theorem. First integrate over $X$ (Expectation with Y= y ) and then integration over $Y$, which is integration over  the distribution of $Y$.

Comment: @Mittens Indeed thank you ! One last thing is that I don't understand why you can't keep $\mathbb{E}[\vert X \vert]$ in the inequality because the reasoning seems to work...